# How build link to local file in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Hello i builded application with log that sow me what i am doing(where i saving files).
Sow my goal here is build links to all my new files that i created and open them by  click

This my code

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(filepath), false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));
sw.Write(Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255").GetString(byteArray1255));
sw.Close();
rtx_Log.Text+= filepath;
```

here i created some file and i just want to show the pass in richtextbox and open it by click.

Comment: I know it just a example my goal here is to make this filepath in richtextbox to work like link and open the file,but thanx any for sowing me the misstake))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `RichTextBox.DetectUrls` is set to true, the control will automatically detect links from the protocol and create a link.

"My File:  file://c:/MyFile.txt"    will display the file:// part as a link.

The `RichTextBox.LinkClicked` event is fired when the user clicks a link - and you can act on it as needed.

```
private void RichTextBox1OnLinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
  var filePath = new Uri(e.LinkText).AbsolutePath;
}
```